# Installing theme problem in drupal

Tags: drupal

I am new to Drupal. I am trying to create a custom theme. I have created one with the help of other themes.  I put my theme folder in sites/all/theam folder.

Now when try to view my site in a browser I see a blank page. So I deleted that my theme folder from sites/all/theam, But I'm still seeing a blank page in the browser.

Thanks

Comment: Would you mention what version of drupal you're using? And what version the themes you used to create your own theme were called/what version they were for?

Answer (score 1):

The folder you need to put your theme folder in is `sites/all/themes` not `sites/all/theam`. Also Drupal won't automatically load your theme, so unless you actually changed the settings to have your theme enabled and set as default, that isn't what is causing your blank page problem.

I'd look into seeing if your webserver is set up correctly, whether some file permissions were changed, or other factors first, before you try seeing what Drupal did, unless you remember changing the theme to have your theme set to the default.